# Programmatically load/unload plugins and change settings in Gedit 3

Tags: python, api, plugins, gedit

We are building a plugin for Gedit 3 using python. The idea is to have preset configuration of plugins and configurations that you can load or unload.
The problem is that we cannot seem to find any documentation that is usefull.
Has anyone tried this? Is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All settings for gedit and gedit plugins can be modified using [GSettings](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSettings.html) API along with Python introspection (PyGObject). Which plugins are loaded is at the key `org.gnome.gedit.plugins.active-plugins`. All of the gedit settings and plugin settings are also found under  `org.gnome.gedit`, including some that are not present in the Preferences Dialog.

The easiest way to see these settings, is using the `dconf-editor` command to launch the Gnome 3 Configuration Editor. To change settings in a plugin, you'll use GSettings.

This may help: [Using GSettings with Python/PyGObject](http://www.micahcarrick.com/gsettings-python-gnome-3.html)

Comment: you should go for `gconf-editor` rather than `dconf-editor` (just would need to change at least 6 characters in the answer to edit it)

Comment: dconf-editor is applicable for Gedit3. gconf-editor is applicable for Gedit2. DConf replaces GConf.